# launch native app from browser

Tags: android, google-chrome

My problem is that in my mobile nexus5 with chrome browser, I can launch a native application with a schema or go to another page if failed, everything works well. But in some other mobiles still with chrome browser (in my case, there are mobiles made by manufactories from China like Huawei, they custom their android system like the way HTC and Sumsung do), the browser seems like treating the schema as a http request and open it, and then shows this page cannot be displayed. And also my Javasript code in previous page cannot work anymore.

Is this a bug with chrome or because the android system is modified manufactory so that chrome cannot handle the schema correctly.

Comment: you might want to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/3419997)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, actually I also test intent on both case, it shows chrome in mobile like HUAWEI still treat it as a http request